# Explanation of an unexplored note of Gauss on hyperbolic volume

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry

My question refers to  Gauss's note "Cubirung Der Tetraeder", which can found at p. 228 in the section on the foundations of geometry in volume 8 of his collected works. In this note, Gauss wrote down a result on volume of a special case of hyperbolic tetrahedron (orthoscheme; a tetrahedron whose all it's faces are right triangles), of which I didn't found any comments about in the whole literature. Gauss's result mathematically expresses the volumetric change (volume differential) $\partial\Delta$ of the tetraeder under the variation of the area of one face $\partial341$ and the edge $24$ that is perpendicular to it. Mathoverflow user Igor Rivin helped me understand this part of his result and said that it's a special case of Schlafli's formula. But I found the second part of his result:

$$\alpha^2cotg^2341 - \beta^2tanh^224 = 1$$

($\alpha = cotg 431$,$\beta = cotg234$ are constants since Gauss explores the case where the angles at vertex 3 are constant)

more interesting, and I don't know how to derive it. This result interests me since stackel seems to derive it in his commentary on the note, so I guess it's not one of Gauss's few mistakes. In particular, Stackel uses several relations which I don’t understand as intermediary steps (if anyone needs explanation, I'll write them down in details).

Please explain it to someone  who isn't a professional mathematician (but is quite competent mathematically ) and isn't familiar with advanced concepts in hyperbolic geometry. If you want, I'll be glad if you'll also explain how to compare Gauss's formula with later results of Bolyai and Lobachevsky.

Comment: I've recently made an advance in understanding this formula. This formula results from the substitution: $cosh(34) = cot(431)cot(341), sinh(34) = cot(234)tanh(24)$. These two relations emerge by using the hyperbolic cosine law for the right-angled hyperbolic triangles 134 and 423 (vertexes 1 and 4 are the right corners). Now, the question remains - how to derive from this formula the volume of orthoscheme tetrahedron?

Comment: If Gauss's second formula is correct (i verified it), how to interpret his first formula ($\partial \Delta = -24.\partial 341 $) ? i tried to interpret the dot as a multiplication, but that doesn't give the result of Bolyai. Maybe one should interpret the dot sign as a kind of "vector product", so that actually $\partial \Delta = -24 sin(241) \partial 341 $ where 241 is the angle between edge 24 and face 341.